# Apache URL rewriting not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite the static URLs on my shared webserver running apache2, in order to track the download counts of the files in the `public_html/files/` subdirectory.
I want to rewrite the urls like

```
http://example.com/files/foo.zip
```

into the url

```
http://example.com/files/download.php?file=foo.zip
```

The `download.php` script works fine if I type manually its URL in the browser.

The `RewriteRule` that I'm using is the following:

```
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /files/download.php?file=$1 [L]
```

I tried two different ways:

1. Insert the rule in the "root" `public_html/.htaccess` file. This results in a 500 error when I request `example.com/files/foo.zip`

   ```
   # public_html/.htaccess

   # Use PHP5.4 as default
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Default wordpress rules
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   # My custom rule
   RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /files/download.php?file=$1 [L]
   </IfModule>

   # END WordPress

   Options -Indexes
   ```
2. Insert the rule in a new `public_html/files/.htaccess` file. Now when I request `example.com/files/foo.zip` the download works, the rewrite doesn't, i.e. `download.php` is not called.

   ```
   # public_html/files/.htaccess 

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /files/download.php?file=$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

I'm having a hard time debugging this, because I'm on a shared server and I don't have a quick access to the apache error logs. 
What I'm doing wrong?

I should probably clarify that the url rewriting triggered by wordpress (with its permalinks) works fine.

### UPDATE

This is `files/download.php` used for tracking downloads on my DB:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');

$filename = $_GET['file'];
$basepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/";
$realbase = realpath($basepath);

$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
file_put_contents("request.log", $actual_link."\n\n", FILE_APPEND);

$inputpath = $basepath . $filename;
$realpath = realpath($inputpath);

if ($realpath === false || strpos($realpath, $realbase) !== 0) {
        echo "Directory traversal detected! <br/>";
        exit;
}

$fileinfo = pathinfo($realpath);
$filetypes = array("gz", "zip", "tgz");

$table = "downloads";           // table name
$pk = "filename";               // table primary key
$counter = "download_count";    // counter field


if (!in_array($fileinfo['extension'], $filetypes)) {
        echo "$inputpath - {$fileinfo['extension']} is an invalid download type.";
        exit;
}

if (file_exists($realpath)) {

        $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$table} WHERE {$pk} = '{$filename}';"));
        $query = "";

        if ($count == 1) {
                $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$counter} = {$counter} + 1 WHERE {$pk} = '{$filename}';";
        }

        else if ($count == 0) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$pk}, {$counter}) VALUES ('{$filename}', 1);";
        }

        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query));

        $size = filesize($realpath);

        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename={$fileinfo['basename']}");
        header("Content-Length: {$size}");
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Location: {$filename}");  

        readfile(basename($realpath));

}
else {
        echo "File $filename does not exist.";
}
exit;


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `/` here:

```
RewriteRule ^/files/(.*)$ /files/download.php?file=$1 [L]
             ^--here
```

Comment: Just tried, this solves the 500 error but not the rewriting. `download.php` is still not called.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `public_html/files/.htaccess` you should have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /files/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ download.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:**

Try this in WP .htaccess:

```
# public_html/.htaccess

# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Default wordpress rules
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# My custom rule
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^files/((?!download\.php).+)$ /files/download.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: That's my problem, since my host (bluehost.com) doesn't let me edit the `httpd.conf` configuration file.

Comment: There is nothing much I can do unfortunately other that giving you a tested & working rule and suggesting right ways to debug it.

Comment: Yes I understand. I'll track the downloads using awstats instead of php+mysql, until some other answers.